# java.io.IOException: Input/output error in Jenkins while running Gradle script

Tags: jenkins

Sometimes Jenkins while running Gradle scripts drops this error:

```
12:48:19 > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
12:48:19    > java.io.IOException: Input/output error
```

Rebuild helps, but this didn't happen on old server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by several processes which tried to acquire lock of one file.
Fixed by selecting option "Force GRADLE_USER_HOME to use workspace".

Comment: How exactly to "Force GRADLE_USER_HOME to use workspace"?